# Cannot align label in stackpanel

Tags: wpf

I'm not a `wpf` expert, so maybe the problem is really simple than appear. Anyway, I made a stackpanel with this structure:

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Label Content="Match" FontWeight="Bold"/>
          <Label Content="Foo" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
</StackPanel>
```

How you can see I set the orientation to `horizontal` so I can have both label in the same row. I need also to align the second label "`Foo`" to right. I tried setting the `HorizontalAlignment` property, but, the label is stuck on the same position. What I can do for fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest answer is that you can't.

Stackpanel is made to stack things after each other.

You can do it either vertically of horizontally and you can align the stackpanel to the right or left but you cannot align the items inside it.

You can use Grid or another container instead.

```
<Grid>
      <Label Content="Match" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
      <Label Content="Foo" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

`StackPanel` does not support the individual alignment of the child controls. However you can set the alignment of the whole stackpanel. However its not the case here.

What you can do is put your labels in a `Uniform Grid` of `1 row` and `2 columns`.

```
<UniformGrid Rows="1" Columns="2">
      <Label Content="Match" FontWeight="Bold"/>
      <Label Content="Foo" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
</UniformGrid>
```